# Wpf child form, OnClosing event and await

Tags: wpf, async-await, formclosing

I have a child form launched form a parent form with:

```
ConfigForm cfg = new ConfigForm();
cfg.ShowDialog();
```

This child form is used to configure some application parameters. 
I want to check if there are some changes not saved, and if so, warn the user.
So my On OnClosing event is declared this way:

```
private async void ChildFormClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // Here i call a function that compare the current config with the saved config
    bool isUptated = CheckUnsavedChanges();

    // If updated is false, it means that there are unsaved changes...
    if (!isUpdated)
    {
         e.Cancel = true;

        // At this point i create a MessageDialog (Mahapps) to warn the user about unsaved changes...
        MessageDialogStyle style = MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative;

        var metroDialogSettings = new MetroDialogSettings()
        {
            AffirmativeButtonText = "Close",
            NegativeButtonText = "Cancel"
        };

        var result = await this.ShowMessageAsync("Config", "There are unsaved changes, do you want to exit?", style, metroDialogSettings);

        // If we press Close, we want to close child form and go back to parent...
        if (result == MessageDialogResult.Affirmative)
        {
            e.Cancel = false;
        }
    }
}
```

My logic says that if i declare e.cancel to false it will continue closing the form, but it doesn't happen, the child form remains open.

My guess is that the async call is doing something i don't understand, because if i declare ChildFormClosing in this way:

```
private async void ChildFormClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    bool isUptated = CheckUnsavedChanges();

    e.Cancel = true;

    if (!isUpdated)
    {
        MessageDialogStyle style = MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative;

        var metroDialogSettings = new MetroDialogSettings()
        {
            AffirmativeButtonText = "Close",
            NegativeButtonText = "Cancel"
        };

        var result = await this.ShowMessageAsync("Config", "There are unsaved changes, do you want to exit?", style, metroDialogSettings);

        if (result == MessageDialogResult.Affirmative)
        {
            e.Cancel = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
}
```

The final else e.Cancel = false works and the child form is closed...

Any clue? 
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to show the message asynchronously? Since you're in an event handler for the window, shouldn't that be on the UI thread already?

Comment: @Andy You are right... if i change ShowMessageAsync for ShowModalMessageExternal (not async method) the issue is fixed. Despite this doesn't explain this strange behaviour (i would like to know what's exactly hapenning, you know...) if you post your comment as an answer i will be more than happy to mark it as the good one. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this method is an event handler for a window, it will be called on the UI thread already, so there is no need to show the message box asynchronously.

As for the strange behavior that you are seeing, this is related to the `await` in the event handler. When you `await` a method call, what is actually happening is that everything up until the `await` is executed as normal, but once the `await` statement is reach control returns to the caller. Once the method that is `await`ed upon returns, then the rest of the original method executes.

The code that fires the `OnClosing` event is probably not designed with asynchronous event handlers in mind, so it assumes that if an event handler returns, it has finished whatever work it needs to do. Since your event handler sets `CancelEventArgs.Cancel` to `true` before it `await`s on a method call, the caller to your event handler sees that it is set to `true`, so it doesn't close the form.

This is why showing the message box synchronously works: the entire method is executed before control returns to the caller, so `CancelEventArgs.Cancel` is always set to its expected value.

Raymond Chen recently posted two articles about `async` that might be interesting reading: [Crash course in async and await](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170720-00/?p=96655) and [The perils of async void](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170721-00/?p=96665). The second article describes why `async` event handlers tend to not work how you expect them to.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!

Comment: I understand why it is happening.  This does not give any hints for how to proceed.

Comment: @Arrow_Raider in the case of this question, the solution is to not show the message box asynchronously. This method will already be called on the UI thread, so the message box should be just be shown synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with using async/await in `OnClosing` is, as Andy explained, that as soon as the await statement is executed, control is returned to the caller and the closing process continues.

We can work around this by making another round trip back to `OnClosing` after awaiting, this time with a flag to indicate whether to actually close or not, but the problem is that calling `Close` while the Window is already closing, is not allowed and throws an exception.

The way to solve this issue is to simply defer the execution of `Close` to after the current closing process, at which point it becomes valid again to close the window.

I wanted to do something like this to allow the user to handle async closing logic in the ViewModel.

I don't know if there are other edge cases that I haven't covered, but this code so far works for me:

**CoreWindow.cs**

```cs
public class CoreWindow : Window
{
    private bool _isClosing;
    private bool _canClose;

    private BaseDialogViewModel ViewModel => (BaseDialogViewModel) DataContext;

    public CoreWindow()
    {
        DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;
    }
    
    private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OldValue is BaseDialogViewModel oldDataContext)
        {
            oldDataContext.Closed -= OnViewModelClosed;
        }

        if (e.NewValue is BaseDialogViewModel newDataContext)
        {
            newDataContext.Closed += OnViewModelClosed;
        }
    }

    private void OnViewModelClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_isClosing)
        {
            _isClosing = true;
            Close();
        }
    }

    protected override async void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewModel == null)
        {
            base.OnClosing(e);
            return;
        }

        if (!_canClose)
        {
            // Immediately cancel closing, because the decision
            // to cancel is made in the ViewModel and not here
            e.Cancel = true;
            base.OnClosing(e);

            try
            {
                // Ask ViewModel if allowed to close
                bool closed = await ViewModel.OnClosing();

                if (closed)
                {
                    // Set _canClose to true, so that when we call Close again
                    // and return to this method, we proceed to close as usual
                    _canClose = true;

                    // Close cannot be called while Window is in closing state, so use
                    // InvokeAsync to defer execution of Close after OnClosing returns
                    _ = Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(Close, DispatcherPriority.Normal);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO: Log exception
            }
            finally
            {
                _isClosing = false;
            }
        }

        base.OnClosing(e);
    }
}
```

**BaseDialogViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class BaseDialogViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public event EventHandler Closed;

    public bool? DialogResult { get; set; }

    public void Close()
    {
        Closed?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Override to add custom logic while dialog is closing
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True if should close dialog, otherwise false</returns>
    public virtual Task<bool> OnClosing()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

BaseViewModel just contains some validation and property notification stuff, not really relevant to show here.

Big thanks to [Rick Strahl](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Sep/02/WPF-Window-Closing-Errors) for the Dispatcher solution!

**UPDATE:**
It's possible to use `await Task.Yield();` instead of `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`.